# Where do I find my bitcoins after buying from an ATM?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, bitcoin-atm

I don't know where to find my bitcoins. I have a receipt from the ATM: [image: ATM-Receipt] and the transaction is confirmed: [image: transaction confirmation]

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase bitcoins at an ATM, you have to provide a destination where they'll deliver the bitcoins. Recipient information is provided in form of *addresses*. The receipt shows an address to which the ATM delivered the bitcoins. As pointed out by other answers, the [bitcoins were actually sent to that address](https://blockexplorer.com/address/1LacZjntH84Ap6FPEkb5UBxpZqjH9dw7F4).

The question is now, how did you provide the destination address for the purchase? Did you perhaps show a QR code from a wallet on your phone, or had a printed QR code that you got scanned by the ATM? The bitcoins would have been received to the corresponding wallet, e.g. on your phone if it was a mobile phone wallet.

Comment: Yes i opened app from phone & then scanned qr code provided to me from bitcoin wallet & scanned to atm. But i still have no coins??

Comment: Are you sure the address was your own and not that of a previous business partner of your? Was the address that you scanned one of your own "receive addresses"? What do you see when you log into their web interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with the adress. Are there any other codes on the receipt? If so, download https://electrum.org/#home and try to import them on there.

Comment: Yes i have a transaction id:

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to this address?

If not, then you bought someone else some bitcoins.

https://blockexplorer.com/address/1LacZjntH84Ap6FPEkb5UBxpZqjH9dw7F4

Comment: Yes i have the qr code provided by blockchain & yes i did open app from my phone & scanned qr code. So idk where or why coins arenr showing up in my wallet?

Comment: The coins are now controlled by the person who holds the private key for address 1LacZjntH84Ap6FPEkb5UBxpZqjH9dw7F4. If you were using your phone-wallet correctly, then that person is you. So the question is: does address 1LacZjntH84Ap6FPEkb5UBxpZqjH9dw7F4 belong to you or to someone else? If it belongs to you, then your wallet will hold its private key (**which you must never disclose to anyone!!**). If 1LacZjntH84Ap6FPEkb5UBxpZqjH9dw7F4 belongs to someone else, then they've got your 0.0476727 BTC.